# MaterialDesignXamlToolkit with WPF class library?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Sorry for the duplicate, but my low reputation does not allow me to comment on posts.

i am trying to use MaterialDesignXamlToolkit with WPF with class library, exactly as in this post: [How to include MaterialDesignXamlToolkit to WPF class library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55594443/how-to-include-materialdesignxamltoolkit-to-wpf-class-library)

-so i installed Material Design nuGet and added ResourceDictionary named MaterialDesign.xaml, where I copied and paste this code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

then I created a new WPF page where I added Resource, so my xaml looks like this:

```
<Page x:Class="test.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="Page1"

  xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
  TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
  TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
  TextElement.FontSize="13"
  TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
  TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
  Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
  FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}">
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyAsembly;component/ResourceDictionary/MaterialDesign.xaml" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <materialDesign:Card Padding="32" Margin="16">
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignTitleTextBlock}">My First Material Design App</TextBlock>
    </materialDesign:Card>
</Grid>
```

Of course I got an error: **The resource {MaterialDesignBody, MaterialDesignPaper, MaterialDesignFont} could not be resolved**

as *@Marija Rakic* mentions in the post, I dried to add dummy lines to my Page1.xaml.cs class

```
using MaterialDesignColors;
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            ColorZoneAssist.SetMode(new GroupBox(), ColorZoneMode.Accent);
            Hue hue = new Hue("name", System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(1, 2, 3, 4), System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(1, 5, 6, 7));
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't help. The error was still there. So I tried *@Trygve* solution and created one more class named MaterialDesign.xaml.cs where I added an assembly

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;

namespace test
{
    partial class MaterialDesign: ResourceDictionary
    {
        public MaterialDesign() {
            Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll"));
            Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "MaterialDesignColors.dll"));
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

and added a reference to MaterialDesign.xaml:

```
x:Class="test.MaterialDesign"
```

but it also didn't work and mentioned error is still there.I don't know where I'm making a mistake ..

Comment: Can you please show me whole MaterialDesign.xaml and code, which actually displays your Page? I only found way to display Window, but not Page...

Comment: MaterialDesign.xaml contains only material design resources import and then you need to add this resources to page via Page.Resources in xaml as I showed below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to merge the resource dictinary before the XAML markup is parsed:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary()
        { 
            Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/YourAssembly;component/MaterialDesign.xaml") 
        });
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i get it running:

**App.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="PRWSolution.UI.View.Shell.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PRWSolution.UI.View"
    xmlns:language="clr-namespace:PRWSolution.UI.Properties.Langs"
    xmlns:setting="clr-namespace:PRWSolution.UI.Properties"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Medium"
    TextElement.FontSize="14"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="None"
    FontFamily="{materialDesign:MaterialDesignFont}"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="800" 
    Width="1080">
```

Also a big help is the Homepage from MaterialDesign. When you follow the instructions it will work for sure.
[MaterialDesign In XAML](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/home)

Comment: the problem is that I use a **class library** that does not contain app.xaml (application definition)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @mm8, I added it to page.resources in xaml:

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/pageTest;component/MaterialDesign.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Hello Mbanch, 

Could you please provide a more complete answer?
Why does this work for you?
Why did you add this?